# Conjectures inspired by AI

Tags: rt.representation-theory, soft-question, knot-theory, machine-learning, experimental-mathematics

Today in Nature a [paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-021-04086-x#ref-CR32) described how AI guided mathematicians to make highly non-trivial conjectures, which they managed to prove, one in Knot Theory involving a new invariant, the other in Representation Theory. The proof of the former result is in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.15323), while the latter result is in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.15161). The github repository is [here](https://github.com/deepmind/mathematics_conjectures).

What are other areas where AI-inspired conjectures have a great chance of being discovered? I would especially be interested by topics related to Dynamical Systems.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/q/92148/30186

Comment: Also a recent question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408778/deep-learning-for-knot-theory-classification/

Comment: I'm pretty sure number theory will benefit from this kind of approach.

Comment: What is a "repo"?

Comment: Related: [Have new conjectures generated by the Ramanujan machine been proven?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/335960)

Comment: @GerryMyerson: "repository"

Comment: Thanks for the related questions. It seems that they are not quite the same though, for instance the Nature paper makes the cover of the issue (so is deemed especially noteworthy) and there is an editorial stressing that this is a first, see https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-021-03593-1

Comment: Another closely related question: https://mathoverflow.net/q/390174/2051

Comment: @DanielMoskovich : thanks, indeed related and the last part of Will Sawin's answer on Kirby calculus is the kind of answer I am looking for my question.

Comment: Yet another closely related question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/410149

Comment: Comments by Williamson can be read here https://theconversation.com/mathematical-discoveries-take-intuition-and-creativity-and-now-a-little-help-from-ai-172900

Answer (score 7):

The PO seems to be especially interested in dynamical systems. `

[`Here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.08323.pdf)  is an article where a deep learning **Long Short-Term Memory (LSTM)** network (see this [reference](https://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/)  for the architecture) can be used to reconstruct an underlying dynamical system from a set of data points without prior assumptions.

It should be pointed out that most models generated by deep learners are not easy to understand. However, recent works goes in the direction of **explainability** across all Machine Learning, and there are tools even for deep networks (there is a substantil literature in this space, and also tools. For instance, if someone likes Pytorch, as I do, for his/her experiments, one may leverage **SHAP**  or other tools, see this basic [article here](https://towardsdatascience.com/pytorch-shap-explainable-convolutional-neural-networks-ece5f04c374f) .

So, summing up: a researcher could use a recurrent deep network to ' interpolate" data points and generate a non-linear dynamics, then leverage some explainer to extract  a simplified and more human  digestible model. As one can run all of the above in a distributed fashion, this sequence would provide a great help both in creating  models, and testing out hypothesis.

Comment: Thank you for the references, nevertheless I'd like to stress that I am interested by provable conjectures.

Comment: @ThomasSauvaget: Provable conjectures are just theorems. Hardly ever we know from the outset that something is provable or not, given sufficient complexity of a statement.

Comment: @AsafKaragila : yes of course, I wanted to say "looking provable given the current toolbox, but whose formulation is unexpected to an expert".